# Black square in the items of the bibliography

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex

I'm relatively new to LaTeX and I wanted to create a bibliography by using *bibtex*. My problem is that when I do that, a black square appears in each item in the list in the bibliography. Like so:

[image]

I'm only importing the packages that I need for the document, which are the following:

```
\documentclass[utf8]{frontiersSCNS} % for Science, Engineering and Humanities and Social Sciences articles
\usepackage[backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{citations.bib}

\usepackage{url,hyperref,lineno,microtype,subcaption}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
```

And to print the bibliography, I use:

```
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
```

I read on-line that maybe this is due to the fact that my article is set to a draft, but it is not. I also read that it may need to use `\overfullrule=0pt`.

But it is still not working if I try that.

Here is the link of the document on Overleaf: [Link to Overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com/read/tyyxpkrsmbtg)

Comment: Perhaps start by not ignoring those 26 or so errors reported by overleaf.

Comment: The class that you use is not compatible with `biblatex` as it loads the `natbib` package.

Comment: It is probably only a good idea to use the `frontiersSCNS` document class if you intend to submit to *Frontiers in* journals, in which case you should follow their submission guidelines and use the bibliography solution loaded by the template (`natbib` and not `biblatex`). If you don't want to submit to a *Forntiers* journal, better use a standard class like `article`, in which case you are free to choose whichever bibliography method you like (`biblatex`, `natbib`, ...).

Comment: That said, in your project the relevant error message comes after some other errors, but on a more modern system (if you choose TeX Live 2019 in the menu and delete the cache), the relevant error is the first error `biblatex Error: Incompatible package 'natbib'.`