# Change plain.bst authors to first+et al

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, citing, bibliographystyle, bst

In the plain.bst file, I need to modify the authors so that only the first author appears, followed by "et al". I'm stressing that, for reasons not worth mentioning here, this has to be done at the bst level (I cannot use other solutions such as replacing with another bst or some usepackage solution).

I have identified what is (probably) the correct function to modify, but I am not familiar with this language, and would appreciate guidance on how to modify it:

```
FUNCTION {format.names}
{ 's :=
  #1 'nameptr :=
  s num.names$ 'numnames :=
  numnames 'namesleft :=
    { namesleft #0 > }
    { s nameptr "{ff~}{vv~}{ll}{, jj}" format.name$ 't :=
      nameptr #1 >
    { namesleft #1 >
        { ", " * t * }
        { numnames #2 >
        { "," * }
        'skip$
          if$
          t "others" =
        { " et~al." * }
        { " and " * t * }
          if$
        }
      if$
    }
    't
      if$
      nameptr #1 + 'nameptr :=
      namesleft #1 - 'namesleft :=
    }
  while$
}
```

I have searched high and low, and cannot find a suitable answer for this.

Thank you!

Comment: You wouldn't even consider using `biblatex`? It would be just an option on loading it.

Comment: @Bernard I've tried, but the journal (Bioinformatics, Oxford) format is problematic enough that when I put something like the following, it doesn't even display the bibliography: 
\usepackage[style=authoryear-icomp,maxbibnames=9,maxcitenames=2,backend=biber]{biblatex}

Comment: That's quite strange. Even using bibtex as a backend?

Comment: @Bernard I just inserted the below, and got black boxes next to the numbers,apparently due to incompatibility with natbib (see: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/551582/black-square-in-the-items-of-the-bibliography), which I'm not the one loading. \usepackage[style=numeric-comp, maxbibnames=1]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{document.bib}.

Comment: What should be done in the case of entries with *exactly two* authors? Is it ok to show both authors, or must one use the grammatically incorrect "FirstAuthor et al" truncation? After all, "et al." is short for "et alii", which translates to "and others". Note the plural "s" in "others".

Comment: @Mico preferably it would look like all the others, i.e. "Doe, John et al. " but if it's a must then I'll go for showing the two. The purpose is to reduce the number of words.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer is patterned after [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/26582/5001) to an older query entitled [BibTeX: How to reduce long author lists to “Firstauthor et al.”?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/26575/5001).

I suggest you proceed as follows.

- Find the file `plain.bst` in your TeX distribution. Make a copy of this and name the copy, say, `plainone.bst`. (Never edit an original copy of files from a TeX distribution.)
- Open `plainone.bst` in a text editor. (The program you use to edit your tex files will do fine.)
- In `plainone.bst`, find the function `format.names`. (In my copy of the file, this function starts on line 183.)
- In this function, find the following group of lines:

  ```
        { namesleft #1 >
            { ", " * t * }
            { numnames #2 >
  ```

  and replace it with the following group:

  ```
        {
          nameptr #1
          #1 + =
          numnames #1
          > and
            { "others" 't :=
              #1 'namesleft := }
            'skip$
          if$
          namesleft #1 >
            { ", " * t * }
            {
              s nameptr "{ll}" format.name$ duplicate$ "others" =
                { 't := }
                { pop$ }
              if$
              numnames #2 >
  ```

  Aside: If you change your mind and wish to truncate the author list if there are more than, say, *four* authors (as opposed to more than one author), please change `nameptr #1` to `nameptr #4` in line 2 and `numnames #1` to `numnames #4` in line 4 of the new code block.
- Save the new bst file either in the directory where your main tex file is located or in a directory that's searched by BibTeX. If you choose the latter method, be sure to update the filename database of your TeX distribution suitably. (If you don't understand the meaning of the preceding sentence, you should probably choose the first option.)
- In the main tex file, change `\bibliographstyle{plain}` to `\bibliographystyle{plainone} and run a full recompile cycle -- LaTeX, BibTeX, and LaTeX twice more -- to fully propagate all changes.

Happy BibTeXing.

---

An MWE and its output:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{mybib.bib}
@misc{a,author="Anne Author", title="U", year=3001}
@misc{ab,author="Anne Author and B", title="V", year=3002}
@misc{abc,author="Anne Author and B and C", title="W", year=3003}
@misc{abcd,author="Anne Author and B and C and D", title="X", year=3004}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage{cite}
\begin{document}
\cite{a,ab,abc,abcd}
\bibliographystyle{plain-one}  % <-- be sure to point to the new bst file
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Wonderful, thanks!
There is an error, though. If you want N authors (rather than 1) you should change the *second* line from "nameptr #1" to "nameptr #N". Not the fourth line.

Comment: @FrancescoPotortì - Thanks for contacting me. I've reviewed the situation some more and have concluded that *both* lines 2 and 4 in the code fragment will need to be adjusted if more than 1 author is supposed to be shown. E.g., if truncation is supposed to be applied only to publications with more than 5 authors *and* that all authors should be shown for publications with 5 or fewer authors, then `nameptr #5` is needed in line 2 and `numnames #5` is needed in line 4. I'll update the paragraph that starts with "Aside" accordingly.

Comment: Mh. I did as I wrote in my comment and it works...